# Authentication between ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, owin, katana

I'm currently working on an MVC5 application + WebAPI for some AJAX requests. For the MVC part I use the standard cookie authentication, and token based authentication for the WebAPI part.
I'd like the user to log in using only the MVC site, wthout having to authenticate again with the authorization server to obtain an acess token.

Is it safe to get the access token on the server side, put it in a hidden field on the site and use java script to query for it and use it later for the web api requests? Assuming the connection will be over HTTPS, for obvious security reasons :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the security token to the api as a header custom attribute to the api which you can pre-check and cache it for all subsequent call in the api.